# make python exe return a value after execution

Tags: python, return, exe

So I want to make an .exe file from python (which I know how) but it need to return a string that will be catch by some java. How do I make that since python isn't made to be .exe ??

Comment: Wouldn't you just have the Python code print your output to `stdout` and then have your Java app read the output?

Comment: You could print to stdout and have your java code read the stdout when it invokes python?

Comment: How does java interact with this python exe?